# If loop using timeSinceLevelLoad variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a toggle button that is initialized as true, when it is turned off it should trigger a function that makes a subtraction for each second that passes by.

The variable to be subtracted it named TEMPERATURE, it should be subtracted by 1 every second until it reaches 0. To count the seconds I use the Monobehaviour variable called TimeSinceLevelLoad.

I built I function but the subtraction is never happening, can you help me?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Assets.Code.PowerPlants;

public class thermoPowerControlPanel : MonoBehaviour {

    private ThermoElectric thermo;

    public bool t1= true;
    int temperature;
    private int tempUP = 10;
    private int tempDOWN = 1;
    private int mark;
    private int i =0;

    public thermoPowerControlPanel (){
        temperature = 100;
    }

    public void turbine1State (bool t1) {
        Debug.Log (temperature);

        if (i ==0) {
            mark = (int)Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
            i = 1;
        } 

        if (t1 == false) {
        ThermoElectric.t1Bool = t1;
            if (temperature != 0) { 
                    if (mark + 1  == (int)Time.timeSinceLevelLoad ) {
                        temperature = temperature - tempDOWN;
                        i = 0;
                    Debug.Log (temperature);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

The bool t1 is working fine, I already checked, it changes to False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit too complicated. Maybe you should look into Coroutines?

You can make a method (coroutine) like this

```
private IEnumerator decreseTemperature()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < temperature; i++) // this will make couroutine cycle
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f); // this makes coroutine wait for 1 second
        temperature = temperature - tempDown;
    }
}
```

You can star and stop coroutine easly:

```
StartCoroutine(decreseTemperature());

Stop Coroutine(decreseTemperature());
```

You probably would need to adjust this code to your needs, but coroutine are very useful in this kind of problems.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, Maybe I can use this condition instead

Comment: Try it, I really find coroutines useful. Good luck!

Comment: for (int i = 0; temperature >0; i++)

Comment: I will need to work on this but I will give you the answer because that is a good solution.

Comment: Changed ienumerable to ienumerator. This is correct now, also keep in mind that you have to use "i" in your loop condition

Comment: so maybe I can put the FOR loop inside a WHILE (temperature >0), or use an IF condition that calls the Stop Coroutine ()when the condition is met.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? decresing one degree every one second untill it reaches 0?